# Spring's MockMvc picks up wrong handler method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

I have a controller that contains 2+ methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{uuid}", produces = "application/json")
public MyObject findByUuid(
        @PathVariable("uuid") String uuid) {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/findByStringPropertyEquals", produces = "application/json")
public List<MyObject> findByStringPropertyEquals(
            @RequestParam("type") String type,
            @RequestParam("property") String property,
            @RequestParam("value") String value) {
    ...
}
```

Now when I try to test the second method like

```
 mvc.perform(get("/findByStringPropertyEquals?type={0}&property={1}&value={2}", "Person", "testPropInt", 42))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)));
```

then `MockMvc` picks up the `findByUuid` controller method unfortunately. Output is

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/v1/domain-entities/findByStringPropertyEquals
       Parameters = {type=[Person], property=[testPropInt], value=[42]}
          Headers = {}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.example.MyObjectController
           Method = public com.example.MyObject com.example.MyObjectController.findByUuid(java.lang.String)
```

However, accessing the REST API regularly when the web server is started is working fine. **Is that a bug or do I do something wrong?**

Comment: In your code you are invoking a GET: `mvc.perform(get(...))` however the `findByStringPropertyEquals` method is declared for `POST` so your code cannot address that method with a GET. I'm not sure why the MockMVC layer has chosen `findByUuid` (perhaps because that is the only `GET` method on this controller) but the reason your code is not hitting `findByStringPropertyEquals` is that you have chosen the wrong HTTP method ... try `mvc.perform(post(...))` instead.

Comment: @glytching That was the problem. Thank you :) ... if you post it as answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are invoking a **GET**:

```
mvc.perform(get("/findByStringPropertyEquals?type={0}&property={1}&value={2}", "Person", "testPropInt", 42))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)));
```

However the `findByStringPropertyEquals` method is declared for **POST** so your code cannot address that method with a GET. I'm not sure why the MockMVC layer has chosen `findByUuid` (perhaps because that is the only GET method on this controller) but the reason your code is not hitting `findByStringPropertyEquals` is that you have chosen the wrong HTTP method.

Try `mvc.perform(post(...))` instead.